# how to solve coupling differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have come to this problem.

Could any one tell me in detail how to solve these two types of equations?

$du/dt=cv-u/T$

$dv/dt=cu-v/T+kp$

Answer (score 1):

Add both equations to get $d(u+v)/dt=c(u+v)−(u+v)/T+kp$ Now let $z=u+v$. Solve for $z$ then substitute $v=z-u$ in the first equation and solve for $u$